# toggle css to div based on an custom attribute

Tags: jquery, css

I have multiple divs in a page all using the same css

```
<div class="datumTijd">Speelronde 1</div>
<div class="clear"></div>


<div class="thuis wedstrijd" wedstrijdId="1" toto="1" ronde="1">PEC Zwolle</div>
<div class="vs wedstrijd" wedstrijdId="1" toto="2" ronde="1">X</div>
<div class="uit wedstrijd" wedstrijdId="1" toto="3" ronde="1">FC Utrecht</div>
<div class="vsScore">0</div>

<div class="thuis wedstrijd" wedstrijdId="2" toto="1" ronde="1">sc Heerenveen</div>
<div class="vs wedstrijd" wedstrijdId="2" toto="2" ronde="1">X</div>
<div class="uit wedstrijd" wedstrijdId="2" toto="3" ronde="1">FC Dordrecht</div>
<div class="vsScore">0</div>
```

when i click on a div with the 'wedstrijd' class i switch to a different class

```
$("#teamStats .wedstrijd").click(function(  ) {

console.log($(this).attr('wedstrijdId'));
console.log($(this).attr('toto'));

$( this ).toggleClass( "wedstrijdSelected" );

});
```

but now i have a problem. The selected div should be using the 'wedstrijdSelected' class. So for example, i click on PEC Zwolle it works. This div is now using the other class. But when i click on FC Utrecht both are using the 'wedstrijdSelected'. How can i based on the 'wedstrijdId' attribute only use the 'wedstrijdSelected' once.

Comment: Offtopic: instead of making up *invalid* attributes, rather use the *valid* HTML5 [`data-*` attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that class will appear on a sibling node, you can remove it from siblings before adding it:

```
$("#teamStats .wedstrijd").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.wedstrijdSelected')
        .removeClass('wedstrijdSelected')
        .end()
        .toggleClass('wedstrijdSelected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
$("#teamStats .wedstrijd").not(this).removeClass("wedstrijdSelected");
```

This will make sure it's off for all other elements.  This will stop it from deselecting the item you want it on, even for a nanosecond.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the class from any elements that might have it, then apply it to the new one.

```
$("#teamStats .wedstrijd").click(function(  ) {
    console.log($(this).attr('wedstrijdId'));
    console.log($(this).attr('toto'));
    $(".wedstrijd").removeClass("wedstrijdSelected");
    $( this ).toggleClass( "wedstrijdSelected" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add removing of `wedstrijdSelected` class from all childs before adding it to one - to keep it only present

```
$("#teamStats .wedstrijd").click(function(  ) {

  console.log($(this).attr('wedstrijdId'));
  console.log($(this).attr('toto'));

  $('#teamStats div').removeClass('wedstrijdSelected')

  $( this ).addClass( "wedstrijdSelected" );

});
```